# XSLT Loop - Four nodes at a time

Tags: xslt, loops, muenchian-grouping

Firstly I am aware of this question: [XSLT: Loop selecting two elements at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131866/xslt-loop-selecting-two-elements-at-a-time)

However I have not found it to work due to the element structure or I just fail with using mod, one of the two.

```
<input>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
</input>
```

I have the following layout of XML which has the following structure:
- Nodes of the same ID will ALWAYS be grouped together
- There will always be four nodes to one ID

I wish to be able to select the four nodes of one ID at a time and loop through each group of four, so that I can manipulate the data into one output line.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="keyByID" match="node" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <xsl:for-each select="node[generate-id()=generate-id(key('keyByID',id)[1])]">
        <block>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            </id>
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
            </value>
        </block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
</node>
<node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
</node>
</input>
```

gives this grouped Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
<block>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
</block>
<block>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
</block>
</output>
```

The output is grouped by `<id>`. Is that what you are looking for? I am not sure. This Muenchian Grouping just simpliefies your structure.

Answer (score 1):

**As the `node` elements are *guaranteed* always to be in groups of 4, the wanted output can be produced by a very simple transformation that doesn't use any grouping method** (such as Muenchian or sibling comparison) **and is probably more efficient**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node">
  <sample>
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </sample>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="node[not(position() mod 4 = 1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<input>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <value>3</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
  <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <value>4</value>
  </node>
</input>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<input>
   <sample>
      <node>
         <id>1</id>
         <value>3</value>
      </node>
   </sample>
   <sample>
      <node>
         <id>2</id>
         <value>4</value>
      </node>
   </sample>
</input>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
2. Another template overrides the identity template for every `node` element that is the `4k+1`st `node` child of its parent. This template generates a wrapper element (`sample`) and then calls the identity template *by name* to copy itself to the output.
3. Yet another template overrides the identity template for every `node` element. This template matches every `node` element but it will be selected for execution (preferred over the previous template), only for nodes not matched by the previous template -- that is for any `node` element that is not a `4k+1`st  `node` child of its parent. This is so, because this template is *less specific* than the previous template.
4. The template discussed in 3. above, has no body and this effectively "deletes" the matched `node` element from the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that nodes of the same id will always be adjacent like that then a

```
<xsl:template match="node[not(preceding-sibling::node[1]/id = id])">
```

Would match the *first* node for each id (technically any node whose id is different from that of the node before it, if there is one), and within that template you could use `following-sibling::` to find the others, or simply define a key at the top level and then use that to extract all nodes with the same id.